# Block Applications

Tags: android

I need to make an application to block other applications on the phone. i tried [app lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248080/android-lock-apps) this code but got different errors like no setp() or getp() functions and many other can anyone tell me steps to implement this code in a service step by step?? .help will be appreciated

Comment: Really? Step by step? No, no one here will make the work for you. Anyway, we will be happy to help you if you provide the source code, some ideas or at least a design of the application. Do not excpect the community to code your app for you though!

Comment: Your major problem is that android is designed with the goal of preventing applications from interfering with each other.

Comment: my code is very big.so cant post all of it. in general i am creating an android security application which is disabling/blocking/locking other apps. major idea is that i am creating this software profile based. there are 4 profiles e.g business, home, default etc in every profile there is an option to select some application and apply security on them mean preventing them from opening. now what i have done is i created the whole software its database but on the activate button i am unable to block other apps through their package name. so i created a service and use timer to kill process

Comment: its running but not doing my desired task. applications are still openeing. i want them disabled

Comment: @user1395965 make your own fork of android

Comment: @numerah have you done it?? i also want to implement it. Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your only choice (for non-rooted / stock system devices) is to create a home screen replacement and have the user select to always use your app for home screen.

You can restrict the applications that can be used by simply not providing the user with a way to launch any except for the ones you want.

[Kytephone](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=kytephone&c=apps) is an application that has this implemented.

Without creating a home screen this is not possible on a stock device though. One application is not able to shut down / block a different one.

Comment: However the home screen is not the only way for an application to be launched.  There are many other sources of Intents which can trigger launch.

Answer (score 0):

Most apps of this type utilize a [signature based](http://guardhome.org/how-antivirus-works-signature-based-detection-heuristic-scanning-and-behavior-blocker/) approach. Crate a MD5 Checksum for the apps you want to block, when that checksum is detected you can abort the install activity. This won't be your whole solution but probably part of it.