# How to block the user from Accessing other Apps in Android?

Tags: java, android

My question is exactly the same as this one [Block Applications](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11018961/2189640). However, there weren't any useful solutions that I could use for my reference. I am an Android beginner and am trying to build an App for a school project which has a functionality similar to FocusLock. For example, I want my app to prevent the user from accessing Messaging or Facebook. While I could get the list of Foreground apps, I am not able to block the user from accessing it.

Eagerly awaiting your suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: As you point out yourself, this has already been covered here.  The lesson you should be drawing is the fact that Android is specifically designed not to permit such interference.  Pick a more appropriate project.

Comment: But there are applications like FocusLock and AppLock which do this. So there should be some mechanism.