# Background service for launching application prior to launch of another application

Tags: android

I am trying to develop a lock kind of application.

First I am displaying list of all the applications installed in the device, and asks users to choose on which applications lock should be enabled.

After user chooses the app, I need to call a lock screen before opening the application.

For example if user chooses to apply lock on gallery I need to start a my app screen for lock before he enters the gallery.

I was able to list all the installed apps but I am unable to detect when the user selects any other app. I have written a service but I can't able to call my app whenever user selects any other application on the device

I want to know how to call my application whenever user selects any other app, How can I detect that ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248080/android-lock-apps

Comment: android will not let you know about it unless you trace the `log`

Comment: I mean I want to know how to call my application whenever other application is clicked

Comment: Follow for my mind. Application start - > Main activity start. You can check, what activity is started. So when activity is start. you can start your service.

Comment: Will it be good to use AIDL or Message service in this context?