# Getting Background Processes in a Meteor App (Activity Monitoring)?

Tags: android, ios, meteor, ionic-framework

I am trying to make an activity monitor-type app using Meteor. I know that both Apple and Android have ways to query for a list of background processes and PIDS. See for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23927405/is-it-possible-to-close-apps-programatically-which-are-running-in-background-in?lq=1) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275578/how-to-get-information-about-free-memory-and-running-processes-in-an-app-store-a?lq=1). What I want to know is if there is any way to easily check for these processes directly in Meteor. Or would I have to develop in base Android or iOS?

I would also love to hear if there are any other similar tools/frameworks (such as maybe Ionic) that let you query background processes.