# What intent does WhatsApp broadcast when it's opened if any?

Tags: android, android-intent

Does WhatsApp broadcast any global intent when it is opened ?
If not how do apps like AppLock know when it is opened ?

Answer (score 0):

In Android there's no intent or simple API to detect when another application is launched. On pre-Lollipop devices this solution works:

[Android Lock Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248080/android-lock-apps)

On Lollipop, you can get foreground app name with new android.app.usage API:

[How to get recent tasks on Android "L"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24590533/how-to-get-recent-tasks-on-android-l)